# Read in a continuous text file into data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, readfile

I have a text file that only has one column. It's like:

```
sample1

color 12
length 34
validity 90



sample2

color 15
length 20
validity 120



sample3

color 34
validity 79
```

There are 3 lines between samples, and 1 line between sample id and its attribute. Also, for sample3, the length record is missing.

I want to read this file into an R data.frame so that it looks like:

```
       sample1   sample2   sample3
color    12        15        34
length   34        20        NA
validity 90        120       79
```

Comment: Please provide a `dput` of your data.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't have an R object. I only have a .txt file that I wants to read into R.

Comment: Got it. Try `library(data.table) ; dcast(fread("test.txt", fill = TRUE)[!is.na(V2)], sample1 ~ paste0("sample_", rowid(sample1)))` perhaps.

Comment: Did you try my comment above? This should be very general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a data cleaning problem. Here is my solution for you.

I copied and pasted your "TXT" file into a blank TextEdit document on Mac, and saved it as `file.txt`. The order as shown in your "TXT" file is required:

```
data <- unlist(read.table("file.txt", header=F, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=F), use.names=F)
data

sample_names <- data[grep("sample", data), drop=T]
sample_names 
## [1] "sample1" "sample2" "sample3"

color <- data[grep("color", data), drop=T]
color
## "color 12" "color 15" "color 34"

length <- data[grep("length", data), drop=T]
length #note missing term, and requires manual coding
## [1] "length 34" "length 20"

length <- c(length, NA)
length
## [1] "length 34" "length 20" NA   

validity <- data[grep("validity", data), drop=T]
validity
## [1] "validity 90"  "validity 120" "validity 79" 

## Assemble into data.frame:
assembled_df <- rbind(color, length, validity)
colnames(assembled_df) <- sample_names #update column names
assembled_df
##          sample1       sample2        sample3      
## color    "color 12"    "color 15"     "color 34"   
## length   "length 34"   "length 20"    NA           
## validity "validity 90" "validity 120" "validity 79"
```

Note that the code might not be generalizable. It is a matter of what the actual TXT file would look like. What's important is to learn to 1) know your data (which you do), 2) come up with a strategy, 3) and then a solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer! But I was wondering if there's a generalizable solution. This is a toy sample that I made up in this question. But my real data is even dirtier. The sample names don't have a pattern (some are digit-only and some are characters+digit). Therefore I cannot use grep.

Comment: There should be a general solution, though it'd be very difficult if your "dirtier" data doesn't have clear pattern. Good luck.